# I see two snippet buttons in the editor

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets, editor

[image]

I'm using Firefox 104.0.1 (64-bit). I see this in Private tabs, too. I also see it in Chrome.

It only shows up on the "Ask Question" page (both in the question editor, and also in the answer editor, if you click the self-answer checkbox). In the edit view, or the answer box (e.g., below, on this very page), there is only one Stack Snippet button.

This may be unrelated, but whenever I try to edit an existing snippet, it pops up a new blank snippet and inserts it instead of actually editing the original.

Comment: Better two than none? :D ... thanks... I'll see what we can do but we probably won't be able to look at this until Tuesday.

Comment: @Catija Please keep the left. It's sinister.

Comment: I'll be sure to pass that request along - no promises, though.

Comment: I see it here on meta, on chrome, when i click "Ask Question". it's not that way in the answer box below or while editing.

Comment: I think that it relates to [this fix that balpha put in earlier today](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9713/circuit-editor-missing-from-ask-question-page). I think we also had [a case recently where the snippets button disappeared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381279/who-sniped-the-snippet) on question pages, so ... possibly that in conjunction with the circuit tool fix? Dunno. I'm not a dev.

Comment: @KevinB That's good to know. So it only happens on the "Ask Question" page. If you check the box to answer your own question, it's also in that editor.

Comment: @Catija turns out it's also happening [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381780/editor-in-ask-question-page-has-two-snippet-icons).

Comment: Fix for this is in a PR, but since the U.S. is on holiday today and this isn't the most critical of issues, it might take until tomorrow for it to get out as @Catija pointed out.

Comment: @DanielKaplan I hope you appreciate the extra work I did to find this out, but I regret to inform you that the left button was the evil twin we had to get rid of. The right button was the true hero.

Comment: @balpha Thanks for looking into it. Consider bringing it back for April Fool's Day.

Answer (score 7):

Fixed now, thanks!

[Catija's theory](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420175/i-see-two-snippet-buttons-in-the-editor#comment925233_420175) was correct, my fix for the missing [CircuitLab button](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9713/circuit-editor-missing-from-ask-question-page) also fixed underlying cause of the [missing snippet button issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381279/who-sniped-the-snippet), so that problem was suddenly fixed twice and thus you got two buttons.